# MVC PartialView not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I am trying to render a partial view within my main view.  however, I am getting the error:

> The partial view 'CompletedJobParts' was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.  ~/Views/Jobs/CompletedJobParts.aspx 
>   ~/Views/Jobs/CompletedJobParts.ascx 
>   ~/Views/Shared/CompletedJobParts.aspx 
>   ~/Views/Shared/CompletedJobParts.ascx 
>   ~/Views/Jobs/CompletedJobParts.cshtml 
>   ~/Views/Jobs/CompletedJobParts.vbhtml 
>   ~/Views/Shared/CompletedJobParts.cshtml 
>   ~/Views/Shared/CompletedJobParts.vbhtml

(sorry about formatting)...

the physical layout (location) of my view is
Views/MDT/Jobs/CompletedJobParts.cshtml and I'm trying to call it from a view in the same location (ie Views/MDT/Jobs/Index.cshtml).  I thought it may be a routing issue so I entered:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        "MDT",
        "MDT/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

into my Global.asax.cs file, but it doesn't seem to search there either (ie, there's no MDT section coming up in the locations it's searching for).

I'm using this to render within index.cshtml:

```
    <div id="parts_div">
      @{Html.RenderPartial("CompletedJobParts", Model);}
    </div>
```

What do I need to do to get my View to find my PartialView?

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it seems you are calling from a different structured controller, try to specify the path:

```
  @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/MDT/Jobs/CompletedJobParts.cshtml", Model);}
```

Comment: Worked for me as well.  Was trying to add a new partial view to modify a layout.  Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

What is 'MDT' and why are you using it as a subdirectory of the Views folder? From my understanding - when trying to render the partial, it is trying to find it in a folder under the 'Views' folder that is named after the type of the Model (~/Views/Jobs/), or if it can't find it, in your shared views (~/Views/Shared/). Have you tried removing the extra directory level?